# Restarting Android activity without redrawing webviews

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android/HTML hybrid application that has a small number of nested `ViewFlippers`, `RelativeLayouts` and `WebViews`. The application doesn't need a keyboard, since it accepts no user input and the on-screen keyboard is *never* visible on the screen, but I've found that if I open or close a slide-out keyboard, the activity is restarted and the entire layout is rerendered, causing the webviews to get reloaded. And if I don't re-render these layout objects, the window eventually gets cleared (turns black).

I can't figure out how to suppress the keyboard event and I'm confused as to how to retain the layout objects (particularly the `WebViews`, which are time-consuming to fetch and render) so that they don't have to be rebuilt from scratch. Can anyone help me understand how retaining `WebViews` is accomplished?

Alternatively, is there a way to prevent the keyboard-open/close event from causing the activity to restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"` attribute to your activity in your AndroidManifest. That lets you handle the event that a keyboard gets hidden or available by yourself. Since you don't want to do anything on this event, it should be fine.

[Further information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)